# i am trying to set a timeout between parts of my code but the syntax ignores the pause

Tags: javascript, wait

```
alert ("hi")
alert("i will generate a random number on the screen and then  seconts tell you it and write it on the screen")
function e() {Math.Random()}
var number45654=Math.Random()
document.write (number45654)
function exec() {
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(new Date());   //It's you code
        },(i+i+1)*1000);
    }
}
alert(number45654)
function exec() {
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(new Date());   //It's you code
        },(i+i+1)*1000);
    }
}
```

i think it might be that that document.write or document.open() ignores timeouts but im not sure

Comment: The pause in your loop [seems to work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/qpu6eomh/).

Comment: for me it just ignores the timeout and does the stuff all after the countdown

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of the problem. You have a lot of excessive code in your example that have errors (and you are never calling `exec()`) that don't seem to be what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems what you are trying to do is:

```
// Function declarations should generaly come first
function exec() {
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(new Date());
        }, (i+i+1)*1000);
    }
}

alert("hi etc.")

// Note that it is Math.random, not Math.Random
var num = Math.random()
document.write(num)
alert(num)

// Note that you should call the function, not re-declare it
exec()
```

Comment: but it still ignores the timeout and says that SetTimeout is undefined for some reason

Comment: Hmm, it works fine for me... On what platform are you running the code? Can you please display the full error?

Comment: i run it on js.do and the error is it just ignores the timeout and reverses the whole code

Comment: Try running it from a .js file or directly from your browser's console. It is possible that the environment you are using is not completely compatible with the ES standards and that's why `setTimeout` is undefined. Also, make sure you are using  `setTimeout`, not  `SetTimeout`. And what do you mean by "reverses the whole code"? @codesforkids

Comment: it does the code bottom to topp once it gets to the setTimeout

Comment: I just went over to **js.do** and tried it myself, it works fine for me, as it should: Alerts a message, writes a random number to the document, alerts that number, then logs the current date to the console 5 times. Did you expect a different output from this code? @codesforkids

Comment: yes i expected it to wait before doing the code when i set timeout

Comment: The basic syntax of `setTimeout` is `setTimeout(function, delay)`. In this example, the nameless function inside `exec` indeed does `console.log(new Date())` after the delay that you set. if you want to `setTimeout` for the whole thing, you should make the whole script a function and then `setTimeout` for it. Notice that as it is now, `exec` does not include the whole script, only the part that logs the current date to the console 5 times.